# Apple Sign-In setup on web page

Tags: ios, apple-sign-in

We have an issue with the implementation of the apple sign in on the web page: Apple recenlty changed the guidelines for the usage of the "third-party login service".

Since our app use facebook and google sign-in service, we cannot update the Apple Application on Apple store since we don't offer the sign in with safari.

So we are developing the sign in with apple in the App and on the web page, but we have some trouble during the setup of the service ID.

We have created a new Service ID with a new identifier id, but when we try to enable sign in we see an error "This request is forbidden for security reasons. The bundle '' is not a primary App."

This is quite strange because the bundle is yet enable as primary App.

We have read that someone else also have this problem, by enabling Apple sign in with an existent app.
Is there someone who can help me? Without Apple login we can not upload any new version of the app. We've already written to the apple developer support but they can't help us.

Thanks.

Below 3 screenshot of the Apple setup.

[image: step 1]

[image: step 2]

[image: step 3]

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

- Uncheck Sign In with Apple inside your app identifier
- Save the identifier
- Again go to identifier settings and enable Sign In With Apple

Now you can add Services Identifier using this app bundle

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to solve this after hearing back from Apple developer support. I had to:

- go to the primary app's identifier
- go to the identifier's apple sign in configuration
- remove the server to server notification url
- save the identifier

Then I could create and configure the service identifier without any errors. After I did that, I went back and re-added the server to server notification url and saved the app identifier.