# How to configure Apple SignIn on an app compagnon website?

Tags: ios, node.js, firebase-authentication, apple-sign-in

We have an iOS app with Apple SignIn capabilities. All working properly. We would like to add Apple SignIn to our website.

On the developer portal we have an AppId like com.company.app. I tried to add a service like in the Apple documentation to use on our website: com.company.app.websignin but I have an error :

> This request is forbidden for security reasons - The bundle
> 'com.company.app' is not a primary App.

But it is a primary app we are using Apple SignIn in prod right now.

Comment: have you found anything? we have the same problem.

Comment: @Lukas it's an Apple bug, I'm waiting for an answer from Apple Support

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apple Sign-In setup on web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63128244/apple-sign-in-setup-on-web-page)